# To send a reminder email using SPD 2013

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, email, reminder

I have a requirement here. Basically there is a list created with column "TO" and "subject" with "Due Date" and"Status".

Any user in the team should be able to use the tool. Fill the details and submit. 
Workflow should trigger an email as a reminder before the duedate to whomever is listed on the "To" Column. 
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow in SharePoint designer.

- Start the workflow on item added event
- Pause the action till Duedate-numofdays
- Seend an Email to TO column

=====================